# Jquery Widget - Events

Tags: javascript, jquery, widget

I am building a simple JQuery widget. My widget builds appends a few items. I would like to know how to properly add event-functions to these newly added items from within the widget.

For example:

```
(function ($) {
    $.widget('be.tagEditor', {
        options: {
        },
        _init: function () {
            var me = this;
            createObj();
        },
        createObj: function() {
            var me =this,
                obj = me.element;
            obj.append('<div class="example">');
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

If I had something like the above, what would be the proper way to add events to the div?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most efficient method is to use jQuery's [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) event binding.  For example:

```
$(document).on('click', '.example', function () { ... });
```

You can define that anywhere in your code and it will fire when an element with that class (here `example`) has the appropriate trigger (here `click`).

This is more efficient than adding event handlers to each item as it is created, especially when the number of elements is potentially large.

*Note:* Earlier versions of jQuery had a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to achieve this, which got [removed in version 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#live-removed). The equivalent to the code above in those versions would look like this:

```
$('.example').live('click', function () { ... });
```

Comment: Note if you do the above you must ensure the elements do not already have a live binding otherwise you will add a duplicate event

Comment: Right, this should go somewhere in the outer scope of the program, not inside a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to pass in an *object literal* to the jQuery contructor. That object can take *anything* you want. For instance:

```
obj.append('<div>', {
    'class':    'example',
    text:       'foobar!',
    click:      function(e) {
         alert('I was clicked!');
    }, 
    mouseenter: function(e) {
         alert('mouse hovered me, oh no!');
    },
    css:  {
        backgroundColor:  'red'
    }
});
```

You can add every event handler to that object literal jQuery can handle. In the above example it's adding a `click` and `mouseenter` event along with setting the `text`-content, the CSS `class` and a CSS property via `css`. To learn more about this have look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/ or, explained in more detail, at http://typeofnan.blogspot.com/2011/02/did-you-know.html.

Comment: Thank you for this, I will definitely look into this more, but for the current, Liza's response works perfectly.